# programmatically finding root directory of pytest before pytest test session starts

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

If I run test cases using command "pytest -s -v"
My test cases will get the root directory path where pytest.ini file is.

But i want to find the root directory programmatically either in "conftest.py" file or from the files from "api" folder before python test session starts.
Please NOTE: I want to get root directory before pytest test session starts

I did lot of search on the internet but didnt get answer for my requirement.
Please help

I have python automation project structure as below.

```
api-automation
  api
    packagename
       __init__.py
       user.py
       payloads
         a.json
         b.json    
  tests
    test_1.py
    test_2.py
    conftest.py
  setup.cfg
  setup.py
  pytest.ini
  README.rst
```

content of conftest.py is as below

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def root_directory(request):
    """
    :return:
    """
    return str(request.config.rootdir)
```

content of test_1.py as below,

```
def test_first(root_directory):
    print("root_directory", root_directory)
```

Comment: Have you tried pytest.config.rootdir?

Comment: @nizar Malangadan, just now i tried but getting following error AttributeError: module 'pytest' has no attribute 'config'

Comment: Where are you trying to get the rootdir? Is it in one of the pytest hooks?

Comment: I tried adding pytest.config.rootdir to conftest.py file, please let me know from where I need try and do I need to do any additional things

Comment: Adding directly in conftest.py will not work (neither request.config nor pytest.config) . You need to either use it in a fixture (request.config.rootdir) or a pytest hook like `def pytest_configure(config):`

Comment: This seems to be what you're looking for: `pytest.__pytestPDB._config.rootdir`. I'm guessing they don't want you reading this attribute directly though given the underscores preceding two levels of the chain.

Answer (score 0):

Define the variable yourself and don't rely on Pytest for it, for example

```py
import pathlib

ROOTDIR = pathlib.Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
```